# can't see Case Record type field in Case settings

Tags: email2case

I am seeting up email-to-case for my org and I want to set up case record type for that email to case, However in Case settings for email to case I can't see case record type field. Is there any changes that I required to make for that? Screen shot for that is attached.

[image]

Comment: Go to setup--> Administration --> Cases --> RecordTypes. See if you have multiple options of case record type to start with

Comment: @Rao yes you were right, I didn't have any record type. That's why. Thanks for the answer.